# Split data.frame by group in a dplyr pipe and keep only differences from previous group

Tags: r, split, dplyr

Let's say I have a data.frame:

```
set.seed(1984)
x <- 
   data.frame(
     num = rep(c(1,2,3,4,5), 5), 
     let = sample(letters[1:10], size = 25, replace = T), 
     LET = sample(LETTERS[1:10], size = 25, replace = T)) %>% 
   split(.$num)
x
$`1`
   num let LET
1    1   g   B
6    1   i   J
11   1   i   E
16   1   a   I
21   1   g   G

$`2`
   num let LET
2    2   e   I
7    2   a   D
12   2   a   F
17   2   c   C
22   2   a   I

$`3`
   num let LET
3    3   d   F
8    3   e   F
13   3   h   D
18   3   g   G
23   3   g   E

$`4`
   num let LET
4    4   d   F
9    4   i   H
14   4   h   A
19   4   j   D
24   4   i   E

$`5`
   num let LET
5    5   h   F
10   5   c   A
15   5   c   C
20   5   c   C
25   5   h   G
```

Say `num` was an hour of the day.  I want to keep only the subset `x$2` that is different from `x$1` based of (for example) `LET`.  So `$2` in this example should be a single vector containing the `LET` `B, C, D, E, F, G, J`; `$3` would be only the `LET` `G, E, C`.

Any suggestions? I would really love to do this in the dplyr pipeline I gave in the construction of the data...

Comment: Have you tried `dplyr::anti_join`?

Comment: nope.  i will see where that leads me.  i suppose i am having the most difficulty not / thinking about this in terms of `lag(...)` or `diff(...)` @Wistar

Comment: `anti_join` returns "All rows in a that do not have a match in b." You can compare `x$1` to `x$2` specify the column and it will return only the rows that are different. Take a look at it!

Comment: yes @Wistar but I want to do this for an array with 72 (hourly) groups and in a window / rolling sort of fashion with the dplyr pipe - hence my thoughts toward `lag(...)`

Comment: You could use an apply function to make the comparisons. Are you comparing each hour only to the next one?

Comment: Yes @Wistar .  Some for of `lapply(x, Reduce(anti_join(.)))` but I don't know how to phrase it...